# While executing Cucumber TestRun file getting below error

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
WARNING: Use deprecated reflections to load ObjectFactory.

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.108s

Comment: Can anyone help me out ....Thanks InAdvance

Comment: Nothing bad. But considering upgrading Cucumber.

Comment: Any idea what fixed this issue?